# Compare two Animated Interpolations objects together in react native

Tags: react-native

I need to compare the values of two AnimatedInterpolation objects in react-native. I want to know which AnimatedInterpolation has the smallest decimal value.

[Interpolation documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html#interpolation)

Unfortunately, `Math.min(value1, value2)` doesn't work.

How can I get the float value of an AnimatedInterpolation object ?

I have tried the following :

```
interpolateOpacity = () => {
    let xOpacity = this.state.pan.x.interpolate({
      inputRange: this.props.inputOpacityRangeX,
      outputRange: this.props.outputOpacityRangeX
    });

    let yOpacity = this.state.pan.y.interpolate({
      inputRange: this.props.inputOpacityRangeY,
      outputRange: this.props.outputOpacityRangeY
    });

    return Math.min(xOpacity, yOpacity) // NOT WORKING
};
```

Debugger:

[image: Debugger]

Comment: Just out of curiosity as I don't do react anything :-S What do xOpacity & yOpacity actually equal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I would do this would be to compare the input values.

If your mapping for the output range isn't significantly complicated, you should be able to compare the input ranges like this by accessing `this.state.pan.x._value` and `this.state.pan.y._value`, or **better practice would be to set up a listener as described [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html#responding-to-the-current-animation-value).**

I don't think there is a way to compare the interpolated values in real-time.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably using something like this.state.pan.y.__getValue(). If that isn't effective, I'd recommend adding a listener to the animated value and using that value instead like so:

```
this.state.pan = new Animated.Value({ x: 0, y: 0 });
this.panValue = { x: 0, y: 0 };
this.state.pan.addListener((value) => 
    this.panValue = value); // value is an object with x and y props
```

Also, don't forget to set and reset the values and offsets like so:

```
onPanResponderGrant: () => { 
    this.state.pan.setOffset({
        x: this.panValue.x,
        y: this.panValue.y
    });
    this.state.pan.setValue(0);
},
onPanResponderMove: (evt, { dx, dy }) => {
    this.state.pan.setValue({ x: dx, y: dy});
}
```